# Supabase localhost connection failed in Datagrip

Tags: docker, localhost, apple-m1, supabase, datagrip

I am following this guide to use Supabase locally with Datagrip: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/local-development#why-develop-locally. However, I could not connect to local db using Datagrip in my MacBook Apple Silicon M1. While the Docker instance is running, I used **postgres** username with both **anon** and **service_role** keys as passwords but nothing seem to be working. Here is the status in my Terminal:
[image]

This is the connection setting and error I get in Datagrip:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password for local Supabase is `postgres`. It shows up in the DB URL in the screenshot. In connection strings like these the username and password are separated by a colon (:). So here we can see `postgres:postgres`.

Comment: Thank you. I just saw your answer. I also figured this out after checking another MacBook Keychain.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. The password that works is "postgres". The Supabase document link above does not contain this info. I found it after looking at the KeyChain password in another MacBook where I had previously used Supabase local with Datagrip.